# How to convert XMLGregorianCalander to Epoch-Time or other fixed integer ?

Tags: java

Is there a library that will allow me to easily convert the java type XMLGregorianCalander to Epoch time (The number of seconds since 01-01-1970 00:00:00?)? Or any other fixed integer for that matter?

If not, is there some neat, boiler plate code to do this? 
This seems like too common a use case to be writing from scratch...

Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
public long toEpoch(XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar) {
    return xmlGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis() / 1000;
}
```

Comment: As Master Yoda says *"Try not. Do or do not. There is no try."* Otherwise I concur :-)

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup totally agree, I won't use "try" but "do" next time